# Por que o jQuery está se tornando obsoleto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, biblioteca

Cada vez mais, eu encontro artigos (em inglês ou em português) que falam disso...
Eu faço mal por continuar a utilizar o `jQuery` nos websites? O que tem de errado com ele? Existe algum outro `framework` (ou `lib`) que eu deva aprender para deixá-lo de lado?
Este [site](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) mostra que eu talvez não precise utilizar `jQuery` nos projetos
Mas... por que eu realmente deveria?

Comment: Se JS puro faz tudo o que jQuery faz com a mesma quantidade de código (ou parecida) o jQuery só tem a função adicionar uns KB's no seu projeto e uns cifrões no seu código.

Comment: o jQuery traz muitas possibilidades, uma forma fácil de utilizar `javascript`, porém ele trás muito "lixo", boa parte das coisas você não vai usar e isso tem um custo, performance. O `ES6` trouxe muita coisa interessante, o CSS3 evoluiu bastante e como são nativos, isso deixa seu site mais rápido. O ideal é que você aprenda `VanillaJS` para não ficar tão depende de um framework

Comment: `Eu faço mal por continuar a utilizar o jQuery nos websites?` Depende. `O que tem de errado com ele?` Mal uso por parte de muita gente. `Existe algum outro framework (ou lib) que eu deva aprender para deixá-lo de lado?`Milhares. `por que eu realmente deveria?` Reuso é seu amigo.

Comment: @Renan poderia citar alguma?
Sobre "Milhares".

Comment: @JeanMichell angular e derivados, por exemplo.

Comment: @Renan O próprio `AngularJs` usa `jQuery` --> https://docs.angularjs.org/partials/api/ng/function/angular.element.html

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o uso de jQuery é opcional com Angular e Angular 2 até onde eu sei. Não conheço as particularidades de cada versão, mas acredito que inicialmente a ideia era usar JQlite ao invés de jQuery.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr do próprio link que você usou: "If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. **If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.**"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**jQuery está se tornando obsoleto?**

Não, `jQuery` é muito bom no que se propôs a fazer que é manipular o `DOM`, é lógico que com `JavaScript` é possível fazer isso, mas devemos levar em conta todo tipo de desenvolvedor, a sintaxe do `jQuery` é muito mais simples para quem está começando.

**Mas existem tantos frameworks novos, por que continuar usando?**

Realmente a leva de frameworks MVC vem crescendo muito, e eles são ótimos com `jQuery`, ele pode ser usado em diretivas, componentes, e dependendo do framework na aplicação inteira e mesmo que você não queira usar, dificilmente vai finalizar um projeto com ao menos um componente que não tenha o `jQuery` como dependência.

**Organização**

Creio que um bom exemplo é a rede `Stack Exchange`, recentemente descobri que usa `jQuery` em tudo, nem por isso deixa de ser organizado e creio que a reutilização também não é problema.

**Mercado**

O mercado ainda confia muito no `jQuery`, não se deixe levar por qualquer gráfico na internet.

Comment: Obrigado. Muito esclarecedor.